# Browser wrong javascript float calculation?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, floating-accuracy

If you put this in the browser address bar (firefox/IE8):

```
javascript:alert(40.34+56.87)
```

Why the result comes as  **97.2100000000001**

when its supposed to be **97.21**

Comment: See [Is floating-point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1864610)

Comment: javascript:alert((40.34+56.87).toFixed(2))

Answer (score -2):

```
javascript:alert((40.34+56.87).toFixed(2))
```